# How to append a .png file into .csv file in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, matplotlib, png

I have generated a graph using matplot by importing data from my .csv file. Now I want to append that graph into the same .csv file. I am using python 3. Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A csv file is a text file. It consists of comma separated values. It cannot contain images.

Comment: Basically, my .csv file is an Excel file. So should I use xlsxwriter to append the image?

Comment: If you don't have a csv file, but an xls or xlsx file, you can use any tool you like, maybe [xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html)?